# Scroll UICollectionView to bottom

Tags: swift, uicollectionview

I would like to scroll the UICollectionView to the bottom so the last item is in the view. I have tried to use scrollToItemAtIndexPath but it does not seem to be working. I want this to happen after I have completed a query with Parse.com

Thanks

```
    var query = PFQuery(className:"Chat")
    //        query.whereKey("user", equalTo:currentUser)
    query.whereKey("rideId", equalTo:currentObjectId)
    query.orderByDescending("createdAt")
    query.includeKey("user")

    query.findObjectsInBackgroundWithBlock {
        (objects: [AnyObject]!, error: NSError!) -> Void in
        if error == nil {
            // The find succeeded.
            NSLog("Successfully retrieved \(objects.count) scores.")
            // Do something with the found objects
            for object in objects {
                NSLog("%@", object.objectId)

                var testId = object.objectId

                println(testId)

                self.orderedIdArray.append(testId)

                var message = object.objectForKey("message") as String
                self.messageString = message
                self.messageArray.append(self.messageString)
                println(message)

                var nameId = object.objectForKey("user") as PFUser
                var username = nameId.username as String
                self.nameString = username
                self.namesArray.append(self.nameString)

                println("username: \(username)")

                self.collectionView?.reloadData()
            }

        } else {
            // Log details of the failure
            NSLog("Error: %@ %@", error, error.userInfo!)
        }
                    NSLog("Ordered: %@", self.orderedIdArray)    
    }
```

Comment: You say that `scrollToItemAtIndexPath` "does not seem to be working". What does it do?

Comment: I have put it under the line `self.collectionView?.reloadData()` but it then does not run anything after that line.

Comment: This is what I am using. Is this correct?`let index = NSIndexPath(forItem:self.messageArray.count, inSection:0)                    self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(index, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Bottom, animated: true)`

Comment: I meant is that the code I should put where the `...`is?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

I have added the lines below to run once the query is complete.

```
var item = self.collectionView(self.collectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection: 0) - 1
var lastItemIndex = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)
self.collectionView?.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(lastItemIndex, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
```

Update to **Swift 5**

```
let item = self.collectionView(self.collectionView, numberOfItemsInSection: 0) - 1
let lastItemIndex = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: lastItemIndex, at: .top, animated: true)
```

Comment: And are you saying that fixed it? If so, that's great! If not, then I'm not sure why this is an answer rather than an edit to your question.

Comment: Also, are you doing this inside the query block, immediately after the `reloadData`?

Comment: It is working and it is outside the `for` statement.

Comment: OK. I don't understand the original question then (because you said you tried it and it didn't work), but I guess it doesn't matter: As long as you've solved your problem.

Comment: By the way, the `reloadData` should probably be outside the `for` statement, too.

Answer (score 9):

For  **Swift** -

**For Horizontal Scrolling** - .right

**For Vertical Scrolling** - .bottom

```
override func viewDidLayoutSubviews() {
        let section = 0
        let lastItemIndex = self.dateCollectionView.numberOfItemsInSection(section) - 1
        let indexPath:NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath.init(forItem: lastItemIndex, inSection: section)
        self.dateCollectionView.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(indexPath, atScrollPosition: .right, animated: false)
    }
```

Answer (score 9):

For **Swift 3** and **multiple sections**

```
/**

 This method scrolls the *UICollectionView* to the last item in the last section

 */

func scrollToLastItem() {

    let lastSection = collectionView.numberOfSections - 1

    let lastRow = collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: lastSection)

    let indexPath = IndexPath(row: lastRow - 1, section: lastSection)

    self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .right, animated: true)

}
```

Answer (score 6):

**Updated for Swift 3:**

```
let item = self.collectionView(self.collectionView!, numberOfItemsInSection: 0) - 1
let lastItemIndex = IndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: lastItemIndex, at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 4):

**Swift 4**

```
collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: 3, section: 0), at: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.top, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 4):

Swift 4:

For Horizontal Scrolling - `.right`

For Vertical Scrolling - `.bottom`

```swift
let lastItemIndex = self.collectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: 0) - 1
let indexPath:IndexPath = IndexPath(item: lastItemIndex, section: 0)
self.collectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: .right, animated: false)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
    lstMessages.reloadData()
    let item = self.collectionView(lstMessages, numberOfItemsInSection: 0) - 1
    let lastItemIndex = NSIndexPath(forItem: item, inSection: 0)
    lstMessages.scrollToItemAtIndexPath(lastItemIndex, atScrollPosition: UICollectionViewScrollPosition.Top, animated: false)
```

Where lstMessages is my collectionView

Answer (score 2):

Update for Swift 3

```
func viewScrollButton() {
    let lastItem = collectionView(self.collectionView!, numberOfRowsInSection: 0) - 1
    let indexPath: NSIndexPath = NSIndexPath.init(item: lastItem, section: 0)
    self.collectionView.scrollToRow(at: indexPath as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Swift 4.2

```
let lastSection = self.messagesCollectionView.numberOfSections - 1
let lastRow = self.messagesCollectionView.numberOfItems(inSection: lastSection)
let indexPath = IndexPath(row: lastRow - 1, section: lastSection)
self.messagesCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition.top, animated: true)
```

Answer (score 1):

Here's my take in **Swift5**:

```
extension UICollectionView {

    public func scrollToLastItem(at scrollPosition: UICollectionView.ScrollPosition, adjustment: CGFloat = 0.0, withAdjustmentDuration duration: TimeInterval = 0.5) {
        let lastSection = self.numberOfSections - 1
        let lastRowInLastSection = self.numberOfItems(inSection: lastSection)
        if lastSection > 0, lastRowInLastSection > 0 {
            let indexPath = IndexPath(row: lastRowInLastSection - 1, section: lastSection)
            let visibleIndexPaths = self.indexPathsForVisibleItems
            if !visibleIndexPaths.contains(indexPath) {
                self.self.scrollToItem(at: indexPath, at: scrollPosition, animated: true)
                UIView.animate(withDuration: duration) {
                    switch scrollPosition {
                    case .top, .bottom, .centeredVertically:
                        self.contentOffset.y += adjustment
                    case .left, .right, .centeredHorizontally:
                        self.contentOffset.x += adjustment
                    default:
                        print("Inavlid scrollPosition: \(scrollPosition)")
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can track top and bottom of your visible view and load next page of items

```
  func scrollViewDidScroll(_ scrollView: UIScrollView) {

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y >= (scrollView.contentSize.height - scrollView.frame.size.height)) {
        print("bottom")
    }

    if (scrollView.contentOffset.y <= 0) {
        print("top")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Swift 5 & 4 Just Call this Function when you want to display the last cell of collectionview

```
//MARK:- Collection view Scroll to End
func funColvScrollToEnd()
{
    let item = self.collectionView(self.colv!, numberOfItemsInSection: 0) - 1
    let lastItemIndex = NSIndexPath(item: item, section: 0)
    self.colv?.scrollToItem(at: lastItemIndex as IndexPath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
}
//MARK:- You can use .right/ .left/ .top/ .bottom
```

Answer (score 0):

**Swift 5** if with animation horizontally

```
func scrollToIndex(index:Int) {
 self.collectionView?.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: index, section: 0), at: .centeredHorizontally, animated: true)
}
```