# How to make UICollectionView scroll from bottom for chat application after reload data?

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, swift4, uicollectionviewcell

I want to scroll my UICollectionView from bottom to top when user click on send message UIButton and when user open the app again the last message sent have to seen first at bottom end.

I just tried all stack overflow answers and other sites code also but can't find any solution to my problem.

[image]

```
import UIKit
import Kingfisher
import Firebase
import IQKeyboardManagerSwift

class FireStoreChatViewController: UIViewController, UITextViewDelegate,UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout
{
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!
    @IBOutlet weak var sendMessageBtn: UIButton!

    var comeFrom : String = ""
    var mChatUser : String = ""
    var mChatUserName : String = ""
    var mCurruntUserId : String = ""
    var isFirstPageFirstLoad: Bool = false
    var lastVisible: DocumentSnapshot? = nil
    var messageList: [Messages] = []

    override func viewDidLoad()
    {
        super.viewDidLoad()
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int
    {
        self.messageList.reverse()
        return messageList.count
    }


    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell
    {
       if messageList[indexPath.row].from == mCurruntUserId
       {
            let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "Message", for: indexPath as IndexPath) as! MessageCollectionViewCell

       }

      return cell
    }

    @IBAction func sendMessageAction(_ sender: UIButton)
    {
        sendMessage()
    }

    func getMessage(mChatUser: String, mCurruntUser: String)
    { 
       // code
    }

    func sendMessage()
    {
       // code
    }

    func updateChatListData()
    {
       // code
    }


}
```

## Output

> First index path seen first while open chat app module.

Comment: have you found s solution for this question?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57290922/how-to-set-data-from-bottom-to-top-while-chat-using-firebase    check this link

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To get the collectionView to populate from the bottom, you can modify the top inset of the collection view as the collectionView reloads,

Call this after calling reloadData():

```
func updateCollectionContentInset() {
    let contentSize = yourCollectionView.collectionViewLayout.collectionViewContentSize
    var contentInsetTop = yourCollectionView.bounds.size.height

        contentInsetTop -= contentSize.height
        if contentInsetTop <= 0 {
            contentInsetTop = 0
    }
    yourCollectionView.contentInset = UIEdgeInsets(top: contentInsetTop,left: 0,bottom: 0,right: 0)
}
```

Then to scroll to the bottom when you want it to do so (in your data source's didSet after collectionView reload and updating the content inset), call:

```
func scrollToBottom() {

    guard !yourDataSource.isEmpty else { return }

    let lastIndex = yourDataSource.count - 1

     yourCollectionView.scrollToItem(at: IndexPath(item: lastIndex, section: 0), at: .centeredVertically, animated: true)

}
```

Comment: Hi, kristian H your answer is right and I already did this day before yesterday, but in this I get one little issue, so could you please further help me on same

Comment: @Meet Soni What issue do you get?

Comment: what was the issue?

Comment: This code and adding become first responder to my textfield in my cell worked for me

Answer (score 0):

After reloading your `collectionview` add the following code:

```
let ipath = IndexPath(row: messageList.count - 1, section: 0)
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: ipath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
```

Comment: Thanks, for review my question, but nothing changes as I added above code in my viewDidLoad method

Comment: before you add this code, make sure that your `messageList` array contains value. Otherwise it wont work.

Comment: in which function you are getting the values to the array `messageList` ??

Comment: func getMessage(mChatUser: String, mCurruntUser: String)
    { 
       // code
    }

Comment: then add my code in that function. After your array `messageList` get the values.

Comment: Ok let's try the same

Comment: I try it and further recheck my code and debug it but can't find solution

Comment: It works for me. Please make sure that you collectionview delegate methods are connected.

Comment: could you please send me your email address so I can send you my entire code

Comment: I replied to you. Please check.

Comment: I Updated the answer. Please check that.

Comment: I just comment messageList.reverse and use your file code not but using this all my messageList data is to set from bottom to top,  can't  update CollectionViewCustomCells scroll position issue

Comment: I resend you mail please check

Comment: Is that your loading issue is fixed?

Answer (score 0):

You may put scrollToItem syntax given in Vinod Jacob's answer inside. 
`DispatchQueue.main.async  {
let ipath = IndexPath(row: messageList.count - 1, section: 0)
collectionView.scrollToItem(at: ipath, at: .bottom, animated: false)
}`

Comment: Thread 1: EXC_BREAKPOINT (code=1, subcode=0x107e0384c) , app crash

Comment: you can try to put index syntax also in DispatchQueue
'let ipath = IndexPath(row: messageList.count - 1, section: 0)'

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277219/scroll-uicollectionview-to-bottom
if there are section this can be helpful

Comment: Thank's for your response, but using this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27277219/scroll-uicollectionview-to-bottom my app crash and I already try this before asking a question to stack overflow.

Comment: `guard self.messageList?.count > 0 else{
       return
    }`
you can use this before collectionview reload.

Answer (score -1):

if you want start collection view from bottom you have to rotate collectionView and it's cells.

**first rotate collectionView in ViewdidLoad**

```
yourCollectionView.transform = CGAffineTransform.init(rotationAngle: (-(CGFloat)(Double.pi)))
```

**than rotate cell in cellforitematindexpath**

```
cell.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: CGFloat.pi)
```

Comment: Thanks, for review my question but I already did this before ask question to stack overflow, in this my chat messages list and my collection view are to be rotated not set index at bottom path.

Comment: I'm getting the issue that when I scroll the table view from top to bottom the list gets hidden behind the input text where the user types his/her message

Answer (score -1):

use this code after loading the Chat from api in CollectionView.

```
DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {

            self.mycollectionView.reloadData()
            self.scrollToBottom()
            //self.table1.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.table1.contentSize.height - UIScreen.main.bounds.height), animated: true)
        })
```